# Update a ViewCell in a TableView with UnevenRows doesn´t work correctly Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

Fill the TableView with so many ViewCells, so you must scroll the page to see the last ViewCell.
If you then update the last ViewCell (change the text of the label) over the Tapped-Event, the label.Text would not be updated..

PS: The ForceUpdateSize is no way the fix the solution, because on iOS the app freeze at the sixth time.

```
<TableView Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection>
            <ViewCell x:Name="DefaultViewCell" Tapped="ItemTapped">
                 <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="DefaultLabel" />
                 </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
                      <!--.....-->
        </TableSection>
     </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

Comment: Can you show us your tap event code please

Comment: `void ItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs e){
DefaultLabel.Text += 1;}`
Simple code to update the Label

Comment: Your label is in the ViewCell I don't think you can do that

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Source-code of this issue is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your sample code , it actually happened the phenomenon your describe. **Although** it not happens in Android ,however it occurs in IOS .**Maybe** there are something difference about `Label` between IOS anf Android.

Finally , I found a solution in IOS. You can set a default `Text` Value to `Label` ,then **Tapped** method can work .

As Follow:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="Accent" >
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection>
            <ViewCell x:Name="DefaultViewCell" Tapped="DefaultViewCell_Tapped">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="DefaultLabel" Text="Default Text "/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
            ...
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

[image]